# Django admin - Add a custom link that runs a a function in a pop up next to a particular field?

Tags: python, django

Hopefully my screen shot will demonstrate what im trying to achieve. Basically i have a function which checks all the current "DMVPN DSL IPs" in the database and then returns the lowest free IP, this part is done. However i want to be able to run that function in a pop up next to that field in the admin page. so when i add a new IP i can check which is free and use that one in the field

is what im after possible?

[image: link sample]

## EDIT

would it be less complex if the function run in the page and populated the field next to it?

ie. click find free ip and then it would populate the field to the left with the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible and you have some way to achieve your goal:

- write a custom [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/), then use it on your admin form. The widget will include all the logic and the graphics of your popup
- write inside the `find free ip` the javascript code logic, e.g. `<a href='#' onclick="yourfunc()">find free ip</a>`
- use the `onclick="return showAdminPopup(url);"` in order to open a popup inside the admin, where `url` is your view with the "find free ip" logic. `showAdminPopup()` provided by the javascript inside django admin.

For each solution you'll have to write the ajax request from javascript and the view on the django backend in order to have a response with the IP free on your VPN. Basically in that view the response will be the result of your free ip function. 
Then if the popup is a new browser window or a layer (like modal or tips) you'll have to write a little bit of css and html.

Comment: what if i didnt have it in a popop? as above?

Comment: I think you can use a hidden div or an iframe or something else written in JavaScript in order to modify your page DOM and manage the logic of your form. It could be done with a little bit of work, overriding the admin templates, writing JavaScript logic and then the view that respond to the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by writing javascript code in a file custom.js:

```
(function ($) {
    function findFreeIp() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/custom/findFreeIp",
            success: function(response) {
                         $("input#id_field_name").val(response);
                     }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input#id_field_name").after(' <a href="javascript: findFreeIp();">Find Free IP</a>');
    });
}(this.jQuery));
```

Add below line in your settings.py if not already there:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
```

Create a folder static in the same folder which has your app. For simplicity and tracking, create `static/app_name/js/custom.js`

In your forms.py add below line in the showroom data form:

```
class Media:
    js = ('app_name/js/custom.js',)
```

Now all you have to do is to write a custom view to return IP address

Note: Don't forget to add `@login_required` in your custom view, and do proper validations in case this is role based functionality.